# AKG 414s in field recording.

Tags: microphone, field-recording, nature-recording

Hello again, 
Thank you for the help with the B&K 4006s.
While I'm at it.. I wonder if anyone has used a matched pair of 414s in the field for nature recording and if so .. what basket/mounts would be best to use with them?

Thanks 
Phil.

Answer (score 1):

A pair of 414's would be a slighly unusual thing to use in outdoors nature recording. It is more usual to use small diaphram condensor mics, as they tend to have a more neutral (less flattering) response than large diaphram mics. Trying to protect them from wind could also be quite a problem due to the size and shape of them as they won't fit into blimps that I know of. You would certainly want them shock mounted, but trying to keep wind out on all but the most calm days would be hard unless you come up with a good custom solution.

Comment: Thank you.. I kind of figured as much.. but thought I would ask the question anyway! You sometimes never know what innovations people have come up with!

Answer (score 0):

I have used a 414 set to figure 8 as the S in a M/S rig with some success.

Comment: yes using them in a m/s configration makes sense. One in figure of eight and one in cardioid, and then decoded later. However, outdoors there still nedds to b a solution for wind protection,and they will need really good solid stands to hold them as well.

Comment: With a little modification, I managed to fit the 414 along with an Earthworks SR69 (the M) into a Rode blimp.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't choose a pair of 414s when doing nature recording. The sound does tend to be more colored, as rockit said. Also, the 414s have those pesky electronic switches, which can be finicky and easy to accidentally change in a field situation.

If you do go with them, though, I made the wonderful discovery that sliding a [Rode Deadcat](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/392861-REG/Rode_DEAD_CAT_Dead_Cat_Wind_Muff.html) over top of a large-diaphragm condenser does a remarkably good job at wind control. My setup for very soft B/G recording is my pair of Shure KSM44s in omni (not the most neutral, but you can't beat a signal-to-noise ratio of 88dB). The Deadcat fits right over it snugly and controls everything but the strongest wind gusts. The 414s have a slightly smaller body size, but with a little modification you could get the deadcats to fit snugly. And at $40 each, they're a steal in the realm of wind protection.

Best of luck!
~Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt,
I have actually just taken the plunge yesterday and ordered a M/S rig consisting of MKH 40+30. I have the AKGs from my old studio.. they're a lovely matched pair and I just wondered if they would be of any use in the field. I'll keep them warm for indoors rec.!!
Cheers
Phil.